# For "Box[+T]", can I say "The type Box is covariant", is it correct?

Tags: scala, covariance, type-systems

Say I defined a type constructor `Box`:

```
trait Box[+T]
```

What is correct?

1. type Box is covariant
2. type constructor Box is covariant
3. type parameter `T` is covariant
4. type parameter `T` in type constructor `Box` is covariant
5. If all of them are incorrect, what's the correct expression?

Comment: "type Box is covariant **in T**"

Comment: If I don't remember wrong, `Box` is not a `type`, but a `type constructor`?

Comment: @Ven Why not just post it as an answer since it's the right one ?

Comment: When a type has a single type parameter calling it covariant, etc. is reasonable shorthand (e.g. "Scala'z `IList` is invariant").

Comment: Using reflection api, we can write ```typeOf[Option[_]].typeConstructor```. I think `Option[XXX]` can be  a `type`, `Option` should be a `type constructor`

Answer (score 5):

About variance from the book [Functional Programming in Scala](http://www.manning.com/bjarnason/):

> In  the  declaration  `trait List[+A]`,  the `+` in  front  of  the 
>   type  parameter `A` is a *variance annotation* which signals that **A
>   is a covariant** or  “positive”  parameter  of `List`.  This  means 
>   that,  for  instance,  `List[Dog]` is considered a subtype of
>   `List[Animal]` , assuming `Dog` is a subtype of `Animal`.

Answer (score 1):

The correct one is :

"type Box is covariant in T"

Comment: "Queue, as defined in Listing 19.4, is a trait, but not a type." see: <http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/type-parameterization.html#19.3> of book "programming in scala"

Comment: Yes, Queue might be a trait, so ?

Comment: I severely disagree with that statement. It's a type.

Comment: Is there any book or articles can explain it? I'm really puzzled by it :(